# Problems in reading existing multilevel partitioned files data from from middle in Spark Structured Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I am working on structured spark streaming with existing multilevel partitioned parquet file as source. I have following issue while using it.

Starting spark streaming job to read data from particular partition instead of starting from beginning.

Suppose if we observed that there is data quality issue in partition year=2018/month=10/hour=10. Now suppose i have corrected that data till date by replacing correct files.

Now Question is how to reprocess data starting from this day instead of starting from beginning? Because in structured streaming lets say i use file stream as source which will load all files i want to ignore few files.  Here i need to remove my checkpoint directory as well because it has offset till date.

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose if we observed that there is data quality issue in partition year=2018/month=10/hour=10. Then how to reprocess data starting from this day instead of starting from beginning?

I don't think it's possible in Spark Structured Streaming (wish I'd be mistaken).

Since we're talking about a streaming query, you'd have to rewind the "stream". The only way to achieve it (I can think of) is to re-upload the data (no idea how to do it) or simply process data that would "delete" the previous version of the partition `year=2018/month=10/hour=10` and then upload a new corrected version.

The question is how to inform the parquet data source that whatever has already been processed should be "evicted" from the result (that may've been sent out to external sources for further processing).

Comment: Hi Jacek yes i think what you are saying is right. I have just corrected my question could you please answer that. Suppose somehow i manage to correct that data now next question is reprocessing only corrected files while continue processing new files in spark structured streaming with file as source.